# JQuery ToggleClass using index attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexing, toggleclass

I have a toggle functionality to implement in my page. I want to show a label next to span element. But the problem is I need to trigger only corresponding labels 


Here is my **HTML** code

```
    <div>
        <span class="header1">Header</span>
        <label class="dtl1 hide  ">Details</label>
        <span class="header2">Header</span>
        <label class="dtl2 hide">Details</label>
    </div>
```

**Javascript** code

```
    $('span').click(function() {
      var selIndex =  $("span").index(event.currentTarget);
      $('label').toggleClass("hide");
    });
```

Do we have anything like next().toggleClass() or use Index of both elements and apply toggleClass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several errors in your code. Your callback doesn't accept the event object. So you are using the global event object (*in some browsers*) not the current event, which can't be reliable. You are also missing the `.` for the `toggleClass` call and `)` for closing the `click` method.

That being said, if you want to select the very next label sibling of the clicked span you can use the `next` method:

```
$('span').click(function(event) {
   // event.currentTarget is typically equal to `this` in this context
   $(this).next('label').toggleClass("hide");
});
```

If you want to use the `index` method, you should also use the `eq` method:

```
$('span').click(function(event) {
    var index = $("span").index(event.currentTarget);
    $('label').eq(index).toggleClass("hide");
});
```

Comment: That was really awesome!!